# ordering a hashset example?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashset, comparable, sortedset

I need an example on how to use a comparable class on a `HashSet` to get an ascending order. Let’s say I have a `HashSet` like this one:

```
HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
```

How can I get `hs` to be in ascending order?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use a [`TreeSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) instead. It has a [constructor taking a `Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29). It will automatically sort the `Set`.

If you want to convert a `HashSet` to a `TreeSet`, then do so:

```
Set<YourObject> hashSet = getItSomehow();
Set<YourObject> treeSet = new TreeSet<YourObject>(new YourComparator());
treeSet.addAll(hashSet);
// Now it's sorted based on the logic as implemented in YourComparator.
```

If the items you have itself already implements [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and its default ordering order is already what you want, then you basically don't need to supply a `Comparator`. You could then construct the `TreeSet` directly based on the `HashSet`. E.g.

```
Set<String> hashSet = getItSomehow();
Set<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<String>(hashSet);
// Now it's sorted based on the logic as implemented in String#compareTo().
```

#### See also:

- [Object ordering tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)
- [Collections tutorial - Set Implementations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/set.html)

Comment: can u set an example of 'youcomparator' please? thanks

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña: No, LinkedHashSet does not sort the set. It just retains the insertion order, which is a very different requirement

Answer (score 8):

[`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) "makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set." Use [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead.

Addendum: I would second @BalusC's point about implementing [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and express
a slight preference for [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which offers "predictable iteration order ... without incurring the increased cost associated with [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)."

Addendum: @Stephen raises an important point, which favors @BalusC's suggestion of `TreeMap`. `LinkedHashSet` is a more efficient alternative only if the data is (nearly) static and already sorted.

Comment: AFAIK, a linked hashset preserves the (temporal) insertion order. It is hard (i.e. inefficient) to use a linked hashset to implement a sorted set in the face of random insertions.  You would need to rebuild the entire LinkedHashSet each time you did a random insertion.

Comment: @Stephen C: I believe you are correct; I've elaborated above. I'd welcome any clarification.

Answer (score 1):

HashSets [do not guarantee iteration order](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> This class implements the Set
>   interface, backed by a hash table
>   (actually a HashMap instance). It
>   makes no guarantees as to the
>   iteration order of the set; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that
>   the order will remain constant over
>   time. This class permits the null
>   element.

You probably need to choose [a different datastructure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) if you want to  be able to control the iteration order (or indeed have one at all!)

Comment: can i make this as a collection set and then use the comparator??
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: AFAIK, a linked hashset preserves the (temporal) insertion order.  It is hard (i.e. inefficient) to use a linked hashset to implement a sorted set in the face of random insertions.

Comment: @Stephen C:  Good point, I hadn't looked very closely, which is why I just linked it under the suggestion of "a different data structure", because the name sounded approximately correct.