# How to sort Strings by frequency then by first occurrence

Tags: java

Hello maybe this question already answered somewhere else, but I could find it.
I have text file which includes

"This text is short and text is short."

And output should be

1 This

1 and

2 is

2 short

2 text

In my code doesnt have alphabetical order it just prints:

1 and

1 This

2 short

2 is

2 text

my code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (sc.hasNextLine()){
        lines.add(sc.nextLine());
    }

    String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
    String text = Arrays.toString(arr);
    String test = text.replaceAll("\\p{P}","");

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(test.split(" ")); 
    Set<String> uniq = new HashSet<String>(list);
    for (String w : uniq){
        System.out.printf("%n%d     %s",Collections.frequency(list, w), w);

    }
}
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: Try a `SortedSet` implementation, e.g. `TreeSet`.

Comment: Do you actually want alphabetically sorted output? Your expected output is sorted first by frequency and then by first occurrence in original sentence, not alphabetically.

Comment: @Justastudent sorry my mistake, as you mentioned first by frequency and then first occurrence, I will edit it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (sc.hasNextLine()){
        lines.add(sc.nextLine());
    }


    String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
    String text = Arrays.toString(arr);
    String test = text.replaceAll("\\p{P}","");

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(test.split(" ")); 
    SortedSet<String> uniq = new TreeSet<String>(list);


    for (String w : uniq){
        System.out.printf("%n%d     %s",Collections.frequency(list, w), w);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're essentially asking for is an ordered hashset.
Here is a similar question: [ordering a hashset example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380312/ordering-a-hashset-example)

All you need to do is add a line before your for loop

```
Set<String> uniqTree = new TreeSet<String>(uniq);
```

then you can iterate through the elements in uniq by doing:

```
for(String w : uniqTree){ 
    // print out the string
}
```

A hashset doesn't have any guaranteed ordering whereas a hashtree will order items by either a Comparator passed into the constructor of the treeset or by the "natural" ordering of the elements that are passed to it. In your case the elements of the hashset i.e. strings already implement the Comparable interface (i.e. you can use compareTo()) which is why you can get away with passing the hashset to the treeset.

References:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html